# Intel asm syntax with GCC: undefined reference

Tags: c, gcc

I am running Ubuntu 64-bit and I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x, y;
    int z = 0;

    printf("Enter two numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);

    asm(".intel_syntax noprefix\n"   

       "MOV EAX, _x\n"   
       "MOV ECX, _y\n"   
       "ADD EAX, ECX\n"
       "MOV _z, EAX\n"

       ".att_syntax\n"); 

     printf("%d + %d = %d \n", x, y, z);

    return 0;
}
```

According to lecture at school it should work, but when I try to compile it with GCC I get this error:

```
/tmp/ccU4vNLr.o: In function `main':
Jung_79913_211.c:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `_x'
Jung_79913_211.c:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `_y'
Jung_79913_211.c:(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `_z'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know GCC uses AT&T asm syntax by default, but I need Intel systax at university. So question is, how I can get it working?

Comment: See the gcc doc for extended inline assembler syntax. You have to pass the arguments to the assembler code; relying on locals having specific names is outdated since more than 20 years. Also you should spefic clobbered registers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things: First, on Linux you don't prefix C symbols with an underscore in assembly, so `x`, `y`, `z` instead of `_x`, `_y`, `_z`. Second, these three variables are *automatic variables.* You cannot refer to automatic variables like this as no symbols are created for them. Instead, you need to tell the compiler to hand-over these variables into your assembly. You also need to mark the registers `eax` and `ecx` as clobbered because your assembly modifies them. Read [this documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) for details. Here is how this could work with your code:

```
asm(
   "MOV EAX, %1\n"   
   "MOV ECX, %2\n"   
   "ADD EAX, ECX\n"
   "MOV %0, EAX\n"
   : "=r" (z) : "r" (x), "r" (y) : "eax", "ecx");
```

You also need to compile with `-masm=intel` for this to work as otherwise gcc will insert references to registers in AT&T syntax, causing a compilation error. Even better, learn AT&T syntax if you plan to write a lot of inline assembly for gcc.

Comment: Working! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This probably the best answer I have seen so far, I searched many online articles most of them saying add "_" to the var if used inline, your answer was better, I had no idea that you needed to specify the IN / OUT and CLOBBER vars on an Intel arch, thanks a million Fuz, your answer really helped.

Comment: @HeiderSati Please note that the example I gave is not actually a very good example for gcc-style inline assembly.  You should try to remove any extra data moves and make each inline asm statement as short as possible.  For example, this one could just be `z = x; asm ("add %0, %1" : "=r"(z) : "r"(y));` or even shorter, `z = x + y` (avoid inline asm unless strictly needed).  Please also read the documentation I linked *carefully* and *completely.*  Gcc-style inline assembly is ridiculously easy to get wrong.

Comment: Don't worry Fuz, your answer is really good enough, the code I wrote wasn't working before I saw your answer, now it does thanks to you. I am extremely good in machine code, my obstacle was to get it embedded my C project. thanks a million, I wouldn't change a thing about your answer, it's good believe me :)

Comment: : "=g" (z) : "g" (x), "g" (y) : "eax", "ecx"); - perhaps better?